# Smart plug with "Save State" after Power loss

Tags: smart-plugs

I am looking for a Wifi/Bluetooth/433Mhz Smart Plug that I can turn on and off with either Raspberry Pi 433Mhz (rpi-rf python package) or any protocol that is compatible with *homeassistant.io* via WiFi or Bluetooth.

The important feature why I write this Question:

Is there a Smart Plug that remembers the ON/OFF State after a power loss of the socket where it is plugged in.

Because I want to put the Smart Plug into a power strip with a manual switch. And if I put the manual switch out in the evening and on again on the next day I want that the smart Plug remembers it ON/OFF Setting

Comment: It is my understanding that most smart plugs won't do it for some safety-related reason. Can't say if it is universal though. But as long as you have control over the smart plug from some scriptable platform, it should be possible to add some kind of "devices is reachable again, turn it on" routine.

Comment: That was the solution, I monitored the state and when it is reachable again i set the previous On|OFF state

Comment: You may want to post that as an answer (possibly with a few details about how you did this in your setup) to help future readers who may face the same issue. Thanks!